# How can I connect IOS project created by flutter to firebase?

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter

I am using Ubuntu Linux,
Is there any way to connect the IOS project created by flutter with firebase?

Comment: Sure thing. Follow the documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup. If you get stuck along the way, report back with the [minimal steps that reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Actually, I looked at these docs but I didn't find the same track in IntelliJ after I search I get that you must use Xcode to add these files .

Comment: Ah, I get it now. Unfortunately you'll need XCode to build an iOS app. Hmm... I may be wrong on that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40567540/is-it-possible-to-develop-ios-apps-with-flutter-on-a-linux-virtual-machine