# Using Flutter from Linux without XCode

Tags: ios, linux, flutter

I use Linux (Ubuntu 20.04) as my development environment. I was excited about the idea of reusing the same code for Android, iOS and event Web.
But I'm blocked because I'm using Linux and in all tutorials and examples are talking about the necessity of using XCode to things like setting the FireStore configuration.

I'm not an iOS developer, so **I don't want to buy a more expensive and less powerful machine** to be able to develop and release iOS applications, and looks like still, Flutter is not the solution.

So my question is, how can I develop iOS apps using Flutter without a Mac?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use a tool named Odevio : https://github.com/Odevio/Odevio-CLI

It's a simple software that let's you :

- Configure XCode
- Create an IPA
- Test your app in the iOS simulator
- Build and publish your app on the App Store

You can install it by visiting the website https://odevio.com/ For a full tutorial check their documentation : https://odevio-cli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You can do one of the following:

- Use a Mac OS virtual machine.
- Use a service to build remotely, like CodeMagic for example.
- Get a friend or co-worker to build the app on their Apple machine.

Also check out this:

[Is it possible to develop iOS apps with Flutter on a Linux virtual machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40567540/6704033)

Comment: Did you forget a link at the end of the first bullet point?

Comment: @Heikkisorsa I put the link at the bottom